# how to query gac for assembly files

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I am trying to learn more about Reflection, and took some code already built and added to it. Now I am trying to query the GAC for other assemblies and build type instances, and etc. I modified the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658498/how-to-load-an-assembly-to-appdomain-with-all-references-recursively), but myAssemblyList is empty. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I debugged and placed a break at "var currentAssembly = value.GetAssembly(f);" and it returns null. All the code I have seen populates Assemblies from the current AppDomain, but I have seen methods like LoadFrom(), which should work with a directory path. I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158170/querying-the-x64-gac) post, and compiled it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
        domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", adevidence, domaininfo);
        Type type = typeof(Proxy);
        var value = (Proxy)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            type.Assembly.FullName,
            type.FullName);
        //String myDir = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\GAC_64\\";
        String myDir = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\";
        List<Assembly> myAssemblyList = new List<Assembly>();
        foreach (String f in Directory.GetFiles(myDir, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            //Console.WriteLine($"Here is f: {f}");
                var currentAssembly = value.GetAssembly(f);
                if (currentAssembly != null)
                {
                    myAssemblyList.Add(currentAssembly);
                    Console.WriteLine(currentAssembly.FullName);
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Assemblies found: {myAssemblyList.Count}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Assemblies found: {myAssemblyList.Count}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
            // throw new InvalidOperationException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I jumped one directory back, and tried to collect from GAC_* i.e. 32, 64, and MSIL. I added a test for null for currentAssembly to address an issue with GetAssembly(). But still some directories that contain dll and non-dll files cause exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify this line:

```
foreach (String f in Directory.GetFiles(myDir))
```

with

```
foreach (String f in Directory.GetFiles(myDir, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out my last problem.

Comment: What was it?  I despair of questions that end in "I figured it out" without what they did